# Convert time json to minutes and seconds

Tags: json, ruby, converters

I have this json:

```js
"result": {
  "status": "passed",
  "duration": 255561500
}
```

I would like to convert the number (255561500) in attribute duration to minutes and seconds.
And what format is this number?

Comment: This is not a valid JSON string, but if `duration = 255561500`, `minutes, seconds = duration.divmod(60) #=> [4259358, 20]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Time.at to convert a value in date type.
This is a basic example as I do it.

```
strJson = '{"result": { "status": "passed", "duration": 255561500 }}'
yourJson = JSON.parse(strJson)
duration = yourJson['result']['duration']
valueInDateFormat =Time.at(duration).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```